# Locking cell content in a word tab in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am asked to create a VBA macro that will create a table, each table created with this macro should have a unique number in the first cell. The user should not be able to modify this number.

Is there a way to lock the modification of a cell ? I can't seem to find it in word vba.

Thank you

```
Sub Tables()


    Dim cpt As Integer
    cpt = 0


    ThisDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=3, _
                          DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                          AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed

    Dim oTbl As Table

    For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        cpt = cpt + 1
        ActiveDocument.Tables(cpt).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Table n°" & cpt
    Next oTbl

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext

End Sub
```

Comment: When you want to set the document protection, is there anything else in the document or is it blank other than 'Table n°x"?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to fill all the other cells in the table. The document would be used as a "protected" form.

Comment: Ok, to clarify the user will ONLY be editing the other cells in the table you create, and the first cell along with the rest of the document will be protected?

Comment: Yes exactly, (he will also be able to call the macro to create other tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is "Yes.". It is possible to protect only certain parts of a document whilst protecting other parts although depedning on what you want to do determines how difficult this may be.

You might want to read the following documentation to help consolidate your understanding of some key references.

1. [Selection Object (MSDN Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-object-word)
2. [wdUnits Enumeration (MSDN Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdunits-enumeration-word)
3. [Document.Protect Method (MSDN Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-protect-method-word)
4. [wdProtectionType Enumeration (MSDN Documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/wdprotectiontype-enumeration-word)
5. [Allow changes to parts of a protected document (Shows UI steps which could be used to record a macro)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-changes-to-parts-of-a-protected-document-187ed01c-8795-43e1-9fd0-c9fca419dadf#ID0EAABAAA=Newer_versions)

***NOTE:*** I'm sure there is a cleaner and more practical way to write this however what I've worked out does work as you want it to.

So with the use of some counters and a few `if...` statements I was able to get the following code working.

The only thing you may want to do is add some code into your `Sub Table()` code to move the cursor to the correct location and unprotect the document before adding a new table (as if you try to add a new table whilst the document is protected it will give you a runtime error).

Here is what I came up with (I'll provide some explanation below the code):

```
Sub TestPartProtect()

Dim i As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim myCount As Long
Dim myDoc As Object

i = 1
c = 1
r = 1
t = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
myCount = 1
Set myDoc = ActiveDocument

myRepeat:
If i > t Then GoTo myProtect
mydoc.Tables(i).Cell(r, c).Select

With Selection
    If myCount = 1 Then
        myCount = myCount + 1
        c = c + 1
        GoTo myRepeat
    ElseIf myCount > 1 Then
        Selection.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
        c = c + 1
        myCount = myCount + 1
    End If
        If c > myDoc.Tables(i).Columns.Count Then
            c = 1
            r = r + 1
        End If
            If r > myDoc.Tables(i).Rows.Count Then
            r = 1
            i = i + 1
            myCount = 1
            GoTo myRepeat
            End If

GoTo myRepeat
End With

myProtect:
myDoc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading

End Sub
```

So from top to bottom; the variables `i, c, r, t` and `myCount` are used as counters.

`i` represents an integer to be dynamically used to reference table indexes. This helps your code work for more than 1 specific table without having to re-write your code hundreds of times. I'll explain further after the others.

`c` represents an integer for the column number the code is referencing.

`r` represents an integer for the row number the code is referencing.

`t` represents the total count of Tables in the ActiveDocument.

`myCount` represents a Cell count. Each time a cell is referenced, myCount is increased.

To explain further, For each cell in the table, if it's cell(1, 1) then it's ignored and the code will move to the next cell. From Cell(1, 2) all the way to Cell (3, 3), it places a protection exception for ALL users to the cell and increases the relevant counters as it goes. Once `c` is greater than the actual count of columns in the table, `c` is reset to 1 and `r` is increased by 1. Once `r` is greater than the actual count of rows in the table, it's reset to 1, `i` is increased by 1 (ready to reference the next table in the document) and `myCount` is reset to 1 (ready to start over again). If `i` is greater than the actual count of tables in the ActiveDocument then the code is directed to `GoTo Protection` which then protects the entire document to read only, apart from the excepted sections we just set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am now able to continue my program thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, because there's only one kind of protection you can use for this: Read-Only protection. By default, when this is activated the entire document is locked and you have to apply permission for editing to any place (ranges) the user is allowed to edit. What you want to do is pretty much the opposite: block only a few places.

While this is possible, it's not simple to block only a cell in a table. It only works by first blocking the entire table, then releasing the cells one-by-one, except for the one to be blocked.

Compounding this, the table needs to be created in an unlocked environment, then the lock needs to be activated on the table. And doing so locks the entire document.

So the following code

1. Unprotects the document if protection is in-force.
2. Allows editing in the entire document
3. Creates the new table
4. Immediately locks the table (removing editing for the entire document)
5. Loops all the tables in the document
6. Puts the number in the first cell
7. Unlocks all the cells but the first
8. Reinstates editing for all paragraphs in the document *except* those in tables
9. Protects the document as read-only

Here's the code:

```
Sub TableProtectFirstCell()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim ed As Word.Editor
    Dim oTbl As Table, tbl As Table
    Dim celRange As Word.Range, cel As Word.Cell
    Dim cpt As Long
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    If doc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        doc.Unprotect
    End If
    doc.content.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone
    cpt = 0


    Set oTbl = doc.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=3, _
                          DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                          AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
    If oTbl.Range.Editors.Count > 0 Then
        oTbl.Range.Editors(Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone).Delete
    End If


    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        cpt = cpt + 1
        Set celRange = tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range
        celRange.Text = "Table n°" & cpt
        If celRange.Editors.Count > 0 Then
            celRange.Editors(Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone).Delete
        Else
            For Each cel In tbl.Range.Cells
                If cel.rowIndex = 1 And cel.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
               Else
                    cel.Range.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next tbl
    For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
        If Not para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
         para.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
        End If
    Next
    doc.Protect wdAllowOnlyReading
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, the code works when I call the macro for the first time, however, after that, the first cell of the next tables can be modified.